# Grothendieck's "La longue Marche à travers la théorie de Galois"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, anabelian-geometry

[It seems](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/) that Grothendieck's familly has given permission for the distribution of his unpublished works, so I hope it is ok to ask this.

> Is there any way to obtain a copy (online or not) of "La longue Marche à travers la
>   théorie de Galois"?

Note: I am aware that [sections 26 to 37](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/LM/LMIb.pdf) and [section 49](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/LM/1lm_main.pdf) are avaible online at the Grothendieck Circle.

Note: a very informative article by Leila Schneps on this particular work can be found here: [Grothendieck’s "Long March through Galois theory"](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/SchnepsLM.pdf).

Comment: (Project) LaTeX version of Grothendieck's "La Longue Marche" https://github.com/gcarmonamateo/LaLongueMarche Contains sections 1-37 and more!

Comment: That user account no longer exists on github

Comment: The link is now working!

Comment: Here is the updated link (https://agrothendieck.github.io/galoispoincaregrothendieck/galois.pdf)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All the manuscripts have been finally made avaible by Montpellier university.

You can find all of them [here](https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/archives-grothendieck/), avaible in pdf.

The items related to “La longue Marche" are:

**La "Longue Marche" à travers la théorie de Galois**

- "Longue Marche" [brouillon] [36 pages]
- La "Longue Marche" à travers la théorie de Galois... [574 pages]
- Deuxième partie: variations sur l'équation des lacets [695 pages]
- La "Longue Marche" à travers la théorie de Galoi [279 pages]

**Autour de La "Longue Marche" à travers la théorie de Galois**

- Théorie de Kummer ? + note Alexandre (bi tenseur...) [15 pages]
- Action de Galois sur Teichmüller [121 pages]
- Paradigmes des courbes algébriques (version provisoire) [33 pages]
- Teichmülleries, 1981-1982 [183 pages]
- Printemps 81 [37 pages]
- Groupoïdes de Teichmuller et les S0 Tg,!v, S0 TG [133 pages]
- Structure à l'infini des Mg,v [189 'ages]
- Teichmüller (1983) [71 pages]
- Autour de La "Longue Marche" à travers la théorie de Galois [135 pages]

Answer (score 22):

This [article from Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/sciences/article/2015/06/17/des-milliers-de-manuscrits-du-genie-des-maths-alexandre-grothendieck-bientot-numerises_4656174_1650684.html) (in French) and this [blog](http://www.neverendingbooks.org/grothendiecks-gribouillis) (in English) are recent and seem to accurately sum up the state of affairs: In April 2012 Jean Malgoire (see the video interview in the blog) donated the manuscript of "La longue Marche" (700 handwritten pages written by Alexander Grothendieck in just 20 days in 1981) to the library of Montpellier University. They have announced on 17 June 2015 that they will digitize the manuscript (and other documents from A.G.'s estate) for purposes of conservation (apparently the text is fading). Distribution can only happen after permission from the heirs. No indication that this will happen anytime soon.

An earlier [MSE posting](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382827/how-to-obtain-grothendieck-s-long-march-through-galois-theory) indicated that one can write to prof. Malgoire to obtain transcriptions of "La longue Marche". The relevant [web page](http://www.math.univ-montp2.fr/agata/longuemarche.html) was removed in 2007 (it survives in this [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20070211071321/http://www.math.univ-montp2.fr/agata/malgoire.html)), and I presume the present legal situation regarding the estate of A.G. would prevent any such informal dissemination (beyond what is already available at the [Grothendieck circle](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/unpubtexts.php)).